# Postgresql and oracle with greater than operator behaviour

Tags: oracle, postgresql, collation

I have a table called `names` with database entries **Rm**, **RM**, **Rnash**, **Rmash**. In addition I am using PostgreSQL 9.1 and Oracle 11.

In Oracle the following query

```
select *
from names
  where name > 'Rm'
```

returns **Rnash**, **Rmash**. However in PostgreSQL the same query returns **RM**. The ASCII value of **M** in **RM** is less than **m** in **Rm**.

Question 1: Why does PostgreSQL query return **RM**? Both Oracle and PostgreSQL are case-sensitive database.

My guess is that it might be due to COLLATE mismatch in PostgreSQL.

Question 2: How do I find COLLATE information related to PostgreSQL and Oracle?

Question 3: What do I have to do to make the output from the PostgreSQL query the same as Oracle's?

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Comment: @rbaleksandar What's with all the bold in the edit? It's not really helpful.

Comment: You can reverse it if you want to. Mostly it just replaces the quotation marks, which were previously used but were not that visible. I have highlighted the essential terms. Not my fault that every sentence includes "Rm", "M" or similar. :D Now you get the important info by just looking (mostly) at the bold text.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your locale's collation rules specify case-insensitive sorting.

Check the `LC_COLLATE` setting on your database. Look at `\l+ mydatabase` in `psql` or `SHOW lc_collate;`.

If you want to sort on the character ordinal alone, without national language collation rules being applied, use `COLLATE "C"`, e.g.

```
select *
from names
where name > 'Rm' COLLATE "C"
```

If you want to use "dumb" character-ordinal sorting by default for all operations you'll need to re-create the database with the option `LC_COLLATE "C"` to `CREATE DATABASE`. This will involve a dump and reload.

You can instead `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN mycolumn TYPE thesametype COLLATE "C"` to change the default collation for a particular column. Leave the type the same as it was before, and just append `COLLATE "C"`.

Comment: select *
from names
where name > 'Rm' COLLATE "C"    giving error about COLLATE.                                                                                                    Show lc_collate is showing value as "United States English".                                                                                                      I have a restriction on altering table or column. The table could be from thrid party.

Comment: @learnern07 Are you on an old PostgreSQL version? `SELECT version()` please. Show the **exact error message text** too. Finally, what operating system are you on?

Comment: Now above given query returns 'Rnash' and 'Rmash' as same as Oracle output.                                                                                                          Thank you.                                                                                              As you are had mentioned earlier, my locale's collation rules specify case-insensitive sorting. How to know by looking at which collation information ?

Comment: @learnern07 It depends on the operating system's collation implementation, so unfortunately there's no trivial way to do so.